# What is the proper way to allocate GPU memory to a member variable of a class?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

Basically I hope to allocate GPU memory to class `Image`'s member variable `frame` with `cudaMallocManaged`:

```cpp
class Image {
public:
    Color* frame;
};
```

But with the following code I got `CUDA error = 1` when allocating for pointer `frame`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// limited version of checkCudaErrors from helper_cuda.h in CUDA examples
#define checkCudaErrors(val) check_cuda((val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void check_cuda(cudaError_t result, char const* const func, const char* const file,
                int const line) {
    if (result) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA error = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(result) << " at " << file << ":"
                << line << " '" << func << "' \n";
        // Make sure we call CUDA Device Reset before exiting
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(-1);
    }
}

class Color {
public:
    double r, g, b;

    __host__ __device__ Color() : r(0.0), g(0.0), b(0.0) {
    }
};


class Image {
public:
    Color* frame;
};

int main() {
    int width = 1960;
    int height = 1080;

    Image *image;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&image, sizeof(Image)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&(image->frame), sizeof(Color) * width, height));

    return 0;
}
```

What's the proper way to allocate GPU memory to this member variable?

Comment: There is a typo in the last allocation call. You do not multiply the height correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cudaMallocManaged`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gd228014f19cc0975ebe3e0dd2af6dd1b) is declared like this:

```cpp
__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaMallocManaged(void** devPtr, size_t size,
                                       unsigned int flags = cudaMemAttachGlobal)
```

So you can use this:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&(image->frame),
                                  sizeof(Color) * width * height));
```

Note: The third argument, `flags`, is here left to use the default value `cudaMemAttachGlobal` and the size is calculated by multiplying `sizeof(Color)`, `width` and `height`.